# PHP - Getting variable value for matching keys on two arrays and converting an array into a string while keeping the variable

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, I have two arrays, as below:

```
 <php?   $array1= array ('firstname'=>"$value1", 'lastName'=>"$value2", 'email'=>"$value3", 'username'=>"$value4");

    $array2= array ('firstname'=>"", 'email'=>"");
```

I want to:

1. get the value from array1 for the matching key and add it to the key at array2 to become  ('firstname'=>"$value1", 'email'=>"$value3")
2. transform array2 into a string as follows: "firstname"="$value1"&"email="$value3"

Answer (score 0):

The first part you can do by iterating over `$array2`, replacing the values with those from `$array1`. The second is what [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query) is for:

```
$array1 = array('firstname'=> "John", 'lastName'=>"Doe", 'email'=>"jdoe@example.com", 'username'=>"johndoe");
$array2 = array('firstname'=>"", 'email'=>"");

foreach ($array2 as $key => &$value) {
    $value = $array1[$key];
}

echo http_build_query($array2);
```

Output:

```
firstname=John&email=jdoe%40example.com
```

Note that output is URL-encoded. If you don't want a URL encoded output, you can simply [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode) it:

```
echo urldecode(http_build_query($array2));
```

or implode the output of converting each key/value pair into a `key=value` string:

```
echo implode('&', array_map(function ($k, $v) {
    return "$k=$v";
}, array_keys($array2), $array2));
```

Output:

```
firstname=John&email=jdoe@example.com
```

If you really want the quotes in the output, just change the callback in the above code to include them:

```
echo implode('&', array_map(function ($k, $v) {
    return "\"$k\"=\"$v\"";
}, array_keys($array2), $array2));
```

Output:

```
"firstname"="John"&"email"="jdoe@example.com"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OjjLF)